What does the phrase 'sons of God'/בני אלוהים mean throughout the Hebrew bible?
What does this particular phrase refer to? What characters in the Hebrew bible are identified as a בני אלוהים? Are any characters/groups in the Hebrew bible identified as the singular בן אלוהים?

Let me break this answer about the "Sons of God" into two sections:
OLD TESTAMENT
In the OT, the phrase "sons of God" fall into two categories:

Extra-terrestrial beings, (presumably including angels but that is vague)


Job 1:6 - One day the sons of God came to present themselves before the LORD, and Satan also came with them.
Job 2:1 - On another day the sons of God came to present themselves before the LORD, and Satan also came with them to present himself before Him.
Job 38:7 - while the morning stars sang together and all the sons of God shouted for joy?

Note the triple parallelism of Ps 89:5-7 -
V5. The heavens praise Your wonders, O LORD— Your faithfulness as well— in the assembly of the holy ones.
V6. For who in the skies can compare with the LORD? Who among the sons of God is like the LORD?
V7. In the council of the holy ones, God is greatly feared, and awesome above all who surround Him.

God's Chosen People


Gen 6:2 - the sons of God saw that the daughters of men were beautiful, and they took as wives whomever they chose.
Gen 6:4 - The Nephilim were on the earth in those days—and afterward as well—when the sons of God had relations with the daughters of men. And they bore them children who became the mighty men of old, men of renown.
Deut 32:8 - When the Most High gave the nations their inheritance, when He divided the sons of man, He set the boundaries of the peoples according to the number of the sons of God.
Hos 1:10 - Yet the number of the Israelites will be like the sand of the sea, which cannot be measured or counted. And it will happen that in the very place where it was said to them, ‘You are not My people,’ they will be called ‘sons of the living God.’

NEW TESTAMENT
"Son(s) of God", is apparently equivalent to "children of God" if we compare Rom 8:14 & 16, 19, 21.  Another closely related phrase is "sons of your heavenly Father", Matt 5:45, 6:32, 23:9.
Now, "Son(s) of God" occurs in several places with slightly different applications:

Humans who are followers of Christ, otherwise known as Christians.  Matt 5:9, Luke 20:36, John 1;12, 11:52, Gal 3:26, 1 John 5:2.  Such are also called, "born of God", John 1:13, 1 John 3:1, 2, 9, 10, 4:7, 5:1, 4, 18, 19.
Adam as per Luke 3:38 because he was directly created by God, unlike the rest of humanity who are procreated.

"Son of God"
Obviously, in the NT, Jesus is regularly referred to as the "Son of God".
However, in the OT, the only time we have anything close to בן אלוהים is in Dan 3:25 where we have (in Chaldean) לבר־אלהין referring to the fourth person in the fiery furnace. Thus, many believe this to be a Christophany.

I really appreciate the passages you selected here especially the parallelism in psalms. Do you have references you can share that share why the first three bullets under your category #2 aren’t meant by the author to fall under #1?

@Don - see some the other material on this site at https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/66497/we-are-told-about-nephilim-in-num-1332-33-why-might-some-interpret-them-as/66500#66500  and  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/85458/what-support-is-there-for-nephilim-meaning-giants/85459#85459

בני אלוהים can mean

Sons of God
Sons of the gods
Sons of judges or rulers
Angels or other heavenly beings

Among those identified as such are the fallen angelic fathers of the Nephilim (Gen. 6); members of the divine council, including "the adversary" (ha-satan) mentioned in Job 1-2; and the gods or earthly lords mentioned in Psalm 82.
Interpretations vary widely depending on translation philosophy and theological outlook. I know of no case in the Hebrew Bible where the term is used in the singular.
